# How fetch all the k8s object which have finalizer attached to it

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to delete a namespace but it is in terminating state, I tried removing the finalizer and applying replace but not able to succeed. Below are the steps and error

```
[root@~]# kubectl replace "/api/v1/namespaces/service-catalog/finalize" -f n.json
namespace/service-catalog replaced
[root@~]#
[root@~]#
[root@~]# k get ns service-catalog
NAME              STATUS        AGE
service-catalog   Terminating   6d21h
[root@~]# k delete ns service-catalog
Error from server (Conflict): Operation cannot be fulfilled on namespaces "service-catalog": The system is ensuring all content is removed from this namespace.  Upon completion, this namespace will automatically be purged by the system.
```

In the namespace I had created few crd objects and my good guess is those are the thing which are preventing it from deletion. Right now I am not able memorise all the crd object that I created.

Is there a way where I can query all the object with the `finalizer: service-catalog`?

Comment: Can you have an example of such object ? `kubectl get object-type object-name -o yaml` ? Do they have any specific label ?

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for all the finalizers that were used in our cluster and this worked for me. It checks for all types of objects in all namespaces and returns their finalizers -- you can probably use awk and grep to filter it out for what you're looking for

`kubectl get all  -o custom-columns=Kind:.kind,Name:.metadata.name,Finalizers:.metadata.finalizers --all-namespaces`

Note, this doesn't return the cluster scoped resources

Answer (score 2):

To get the registered CRD list, use:

```
$ kubectl get crds
elasticsearches.kubedb.com                       2020-03-03T04:05:13Z
elasticsearchversions.catalog.kubedb.com         2020-03-03T04:05:16Z
etcds.kubedb.com                                 2020-03-03T04:05:13Z
etcdversions.catalog.kubedb.com                  2020-03-03T04:05:16Z
ingresses.voyager.appscode.com                   2020-03-03T05:07:42Z
m3dbclusters.operator.m3db.io                    2020-03-02T10:56:55Z
```

Once you have the CRDs, you can find the objects of that type in given namespace:

```
$ kubectl get m3dbclusters.operator.m3db.io -n m3db
NAME           AGE
m3db-cluster   47h
```

To list all objects along with the finalizers, you can use `custom-columns`.

```
# kubectl get <crd-name> -n <namespace> -o custom-columns=Kind:.kind,Name:.metadata.name,Finalizers:.metadata.finalizers

$ kubectl get m3dbclusters.operator.m3db.io -n m3db -o custom-columns=Kind:.kind,Name:.metadata.name,Finalizers:.metadata.finalizers
Kind          Name           Finalizers
M3DBCluster   m3db-cluster   [operator.m3db.io/etcd-deletion]
```

Comment: still problem remains the same I need to query one by one with all the crds, which is tedious task. Anything smart we can do?

Comment: No, there is not a way to access data other than through a specific Kind

Comment: @prashant , If you want do something smart, you can write a script that automate whole the process.